# JPA Hibernate Spring Repository ensures transaction completes on save?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am creating a simple spring application which is supposed to book seats in a seminar. Lets say `Booking` class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookings")
@IdClass(BookingId.class)
public class Booking{
    @Id
    private Long seminarId;

    @Id
    private String seatNo;

    // .. other fields like perticipant info

    // .. getter setters
}
```

of course the `BookingId` class:

```
public class BookingId implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long seminarId;
    private String seatNo;

    // .. constructors, getters, setters
}
```

And I have a `repository`

```
@Repository
public interface BookingsRepository extends JpaRepository<Booking, BookingId>{
}
```

in the controller when a booking request arrives I first check if a booking with same seminer id and seat number already exists, if it doesn't exist I create one

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<BaseCrudResponse> createNewBooking(@Valid @RequestBody NewBookingDao newBookingDao, BindingResult bindingResult){
    logger.debug("Request for a new booking");

    // .. some other stuffs     
    Booking newBooking = new Booking();
    newBooking.setSeminarId(newBookingDao.getSeminarId());
    newBooking.setSeatNumber(newBookingDao.getSeatNumber());
    // .. set other fields
    Booking existing = bookingsRepository.findOne(new BookingId(newBooking.getSeminarId(), newBooking.getSeatNumber());
    if (existing == null)
        bookingsRepository.save(newBooking);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new BaseCrudResponse(0), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);


}
```

Now what will happen if the `save` method of the `repository` didn't finish commiting transaction and another request already gets past the existence check ? There might be incorrect booking (the last commit will override the previous). Is this scenario likely to happen ? Will the repository ensures that it completes the transaction before another save call ?

Also is there any way to tell Jpa to throw some exception (for IntegrityConstraintException if the composite key (in this case seminerId and seatNumber) already exists ? Now in the present setting its just updating the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javax.persistence.LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE so other transactions except the one that got the lock cannot update the entity.

If you use spring-data > 1.6 you can annotate the repository method with @Lock :

```
interface BookingsRepository extends Repository<Booking, Long> {

  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
  Booking findOne(Long id);
}
```

For sure you need to handle the locking exception that may be thron in the controller.

Comment: so lets say I have this method @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Booking findOne(BookingId id);, will the lock be released only after I perform the save() or just after the findOne()?